# Cannot load nib file, however file exists there

Tags: ios, xcode, nib, nsexception

I wanted to create a new view controller, which would be home view controller. However, somehow I couldn't managed to find how this exception is thrown. Having tried restarting XCode, restarting computer, clean project, delete from simulator. Nothing solved. Here are the details:

**This is the exception thrown.**

[image: Exception]

**Xcode's Finder View is like this**

[image: Xcode Finder View]

**The actual folder of app**

[image: OS X Finder View]

**The code block where nib is loaded**

```
#pragma mark - View's life cycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MainMenuCell.xib" bundle:nil];

    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MainMenuCell"];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

**The parent view controller of nib owner is declared**

```
@implementation BNRAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launches

    self.window.rootViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**Nib's implementation file (MainMenuCell.m)**

```
#import "MainMenuCell.h"

@implementation MainMenuCell

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

**Reuse Identifier declared inside IB**

[image: Attributes 1 - MainMenuCell]

**nib's Custom Class**

[image: Attributes 2 - MainMenuCell]

**Copy Bundle Resources of app in Build Phases**

[image: Build Phases 1]

**Compiled Sources of app in Build Phases**

[image: Build Phases 2]

There are too much images I apologize for that, but I've taken screenshot of everything in order to check my consistency. Any idea will be greatly welcomed (having lost like 5 hrs there!!!).

Comment: Please make sure to paste code in your questions as plain text and use the {} button in the editor to mark it as code. This makes it a whole lot easier to read and to work with when troubleshooting and writing an answer. Same goes for error messages.

Comment: @BergQuester Going to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to specify the file extension in your nib loading code. Cocoa automatically handles this for you.

`UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MainMenuCell.xib" bundle:nil];`

Should be:

`UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MainMenuCell" bundle:nil];`

Comment: I don't know how can I be sorry for that. Thanks, you saved me.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, if you don't know after five hours, you don't know. Be sure to accept the answers that work so that the answerer gets credit. :-)

Comment: Yea I'm aware of that, unless SO blocks me to accept your answer as it is too early.